# Concept of $\alpha$ and $\omega$ - limit points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limit-cycles

It is given that a point $(x^*,y^*)$ is said to be $\omega$- limit point ($\alpha$ -limit point) of the trajectory of a system if there exists a sequence of times $_ \to \infty (_ \to -\infty)$ such that
$\lim_{\to\infty} ((_), (_)) = (^∗, ^∗) $.

**1) As $t_n$ is a sequence of time, how can it tend to $-\infty$? Does the sign refer to the direction? If so, how can time have a direction, since it is a scalar quantity?**

**Example:**
I found a system of equations
$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-y+x(1-x^2-y^2)\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=x+y(1-x^2-y^2)$
Transforming this sytem to polar coordinates , I found $\dfrac{dr}{dt}=r(1-r^2)$ and $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=1$. So clearly if $0<r<1$, then $r$ increases spirally to the limit cycle $r=1$ in anticlockwise sense from inside. If $r>1$, $r$ decreases spirally from outside in aniticlockwise sense to the limit cycle $r=1$.
**In this scenario, which limit point is the origin?**

**EDIT:** After having a conversation with Hans Lundmark, I thought it might be good to post a portrait about my question as I am surely lacking of some basic conceptions about positive and negative time directions. So in this picture, which trajectories are for $t\to-\infty$ and which are for $t\to\infty$? And what limit point is the origin?
[image]

I have understood that $r=1$ is the limit cycle and a stable one. But I am having trouble to understand how the $\alpha$ and $\omega$ limit point works.

**Another edit:**

Adding two paths along which solutions approach to the origin. The left side as $t\to -\infty$ and the right one as $t\to\infty$.

[image]

Comment: If the word “time” bothers you, just say “a sequence of numbers $t_n$”. There is nothing strange about a sequence of numbers tending to $-\infty$, is there?

Comment: @HansLundmark That's fine...but how would someone interpret that phrase geometrically? Also how can I judge whether a point is $\alpha$-limit point (in the context of the given problem)?

Comment: Are you fine with the concept of $\omega$-limit points? $\alpha$-limit points are just the same thing except that you follow the trajectories backwards instead of forwards. (In your case, that would cause you to spiral in towards the origin, so it is indeed an $\alpha$-limit point.)

Comment: @HansLundmark As far my knowledge, trajectories from $\omega$- limit points move outwards (because $t\to\infty$ and $=\infty$ senses anticlockwise) while the trajectories from $\alpha$- limit point move inwards. But in my problem trajectories from inside the circle $r=1$ move outwards to $r=q$. So how is $r=0$ an $\alpha$- limit point? If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Your first sentence in that comment makes no sense at all to me, I'm afraid. (In particular, I have no idea what you mean by “$=\infty$ senses anticlockwise”.) As $t \to \infty$, all trajectories except the constant solution $(x,y)=(0,0)$ approach the unit circle, so every point on that circle is an $\omega$-limit point. As $t \to -\infty$, the trajectories inside the unit circle approach the origin, so that's an $\alpha$-limit point.

Comment: @HansLundmark And that is my question. Why $t\to\infty$ implies trajectories from outside the circle tending to the circle? And why $t\to -\infty$ implies trajectories from inside the circle tending to the circle?

Comment: Sorry, but that comment makes no sense to me neither. Consider some particular trajectory inside the circle. If you follow it in the forward direction, you will spiral out towards the circle, but if you go backwards instead, you will spiral in towards the origin.

Comment: @HansLundmark can you please provide me a pictorial concept of this? because I can imagine that forward direction can also take a particle towards the origin

Comment: I don't understand how you can imagine that, all of a sudden! After all, it contradicts what you yourself wrote in the question: “So clearly if $0<r<1$, then $r$ increases spirally to the limit cycle $r=1$ in anticlockwise sense from inside.”

Comment: Phase portrait: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=streamplot+%7B-y%2Bx%281-x%5E2-y%5E2%29%2Cx%2By%281-x%5E2-y%5E2%29%7D%2Cx%3D-2..2%2Cy%3D-2..2

Comment: The only way that you can get to the origin in forward time is if you start at the origin, i.e., if you consider the constant solution $(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$. For *that* trajectory, the origin is trivially both an $\alpha$-limit point and an $\omega$-limit point. (But that's how it always is for equilibrium points, and it's not particularly interesting.)

Comment: @HansLundmark I have edited my question. If you kindly post an answer rather than commenting, I can provide some pictures in the comment of your answer. Is forward direction implying anticlockwise rotation or clockwise rotation?

Comment: The arrows are pointing in the direction of forward time, of course. (What other way would one want to draw arrows?) Since $d\theta/dt=1 > 0$, $\theta(t)$ is an increasing function, so you're going in the positive angular direction (counterclockwise) as time increases.

Comment: @HansLundmark so counterclockwise direction gives us $t\to\infty$ and clockwise direction gives $t\to-\infty$. Am I correct? So how the origin becomes $\alpha$-limit point in this picture?

Comment: Consider a spiral solution $(x(t),y(t))$ inside the circle. Then $(x(t),y(t)) \to (0,0)$ as $t \to -\infty$, right? (If you follow the spiral backwards, i.e., in the direction opposite to how the arrow is pointing, then you go clockwise in towards the origin.) So $(x(t_n),y(t_n)) \to (0,0)$ for *any* sequence $t_n$ tending to $-\infty$, and thus $(0,0)$ satisfies the definition of being an $\alpha$-limit point for that trajectory.

Comment: @HansLundmark but in the given problem (in my question), the solutions inside the circle approaches spirally to $r=1$ in counterclockwise direction (or as I can say as $t\to\infty$) except the solutions that start from the origin. They always stay at the origin. But for being an $\alpha$-limit point, solutions must approach to $(x^*,y^*)$ as $t\to-\infty$. So how does the origin become an $\alpha$-limit point? Whenever a solution starts slightly beside the origin, it tends to $r=1$ as $t\to\infty$. No solution is moving to the origin except those that start at the origin.

Comment: @HansLundmark I added an image where the solutions tend to $0$ in two ways. Can these happen? In these cases, which image indicates $\alpha$ and $\omega$ limit point? [**this question is not related to the problem that was asked in the post**]

Comment: Sorry, I give up – this is hopeless... If you move **BACKWARDS** along the spiral (i.e., you go **against** the direction of the arrows), as you must do if time is supposed to tend to **minus** infinity, then you approach the origin. Isn't that clear? You say yourself that the solution approaches the unit circle as time tends to **plus** infinity, and that is true, but it's completely irrelevant for what happens at **minus** infinity. (Regarding your newly added picture, I honestly haven't got the slightest idea of what it is supposed to illustrate.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for your patience!! I was thinking that $t\to\infty$ meant anticlockwise direction and $\to-\infty$ meant clockwise direction. But it was actually going along and against to the direction of arrows. That's what I needed. Thank you!